# Getting error springboot version 2.x to 3.0.5 and camel version 3.14.1 to 3.17.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

`To fix the vulnerability CVE-2023-20860 issue getting below error while changing the version

spring-boot version 3.0.5
`<java.version>17</java.version> <camel.version>3.17.0</camel.version> <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version> Camel-cfx <version>3.17.0</version>`

Field ctx in com.chubbio.cpngadapter.processor.SetTokenInHeaderProcessor required a bean of type 'org.apache.camel.CamelContext' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

we have changed dependency version in pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Apache Camel v4 for Spring Boot v3 support. So stay on Spring Boot v2 if you use Camel v3.